# How merge two array with unique values in multi while loop php

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Can someone help me to solve this array issue?  I am using a MySQL database, I'm trying to fetch values from two tables in two while loops. I want to merge result as I have described below. I've tried achieving this with the following code, however, this does not work for me.

```
    $jsonObj= array(); 
    $query="SELECT * FROM `tbl_news` ORDER BY `news_type` desc limit 50, 100"; 
    $sql0 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql0))
    {
        $nid = $data['id'];
        $cquery = "select id from tbl_comments where news_id = '$nid'";
        $cresult = mysqli_query($mysqli,$cquery);
        $totalc =  mysqli_num_rows($cresult);
        
        $row['id'] = $data['id']; 
        $row['news_type'] = $data['news_type'];
        $row['news_heading'] = stripslashes($data['news_heading']); 

          //Comments
          $qry2="SELECT * FROM tbl_comments WHERE tbl_comments.`news_id`='".$nid."'";
          $result2=mysqli_query($mysqli,$qry2); 
          $row2['totalc'] = $result2->num_rows;
          if($result2->num_rows > 0)
          {     
                while ($row_comments=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                    
                    $row2['comment_id'] = $row_comments['id'];
                    $row2['news_id'] = $row_comments['news_id']; 
                    $row2['user_name'] = $row_comments['user_name'];
                    $row2['user_email'] = $row_comments['user_email']; 
                    $row2['comment_text'] = $row_comments['comment_text']; 
                    $row['user_comments'][]= $row2;
                  } 
          }
          else
          {   
                $row2 = array();
          } 
        array_push($jsonObj,$row); 
    } 
    $set['SET_News'] = $jsonObj;
    
    header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
    echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    die();
```

I am expecting this result

```
"Set_News": [{
    {
        "id": "104",
        "news_type": "any",
        "news_heading": "Mews heade here 1",
        "user_comments": [{
                "totalc": 2,
                "comment_id": "17",
                "news_id": "104",
                "user_name": "abhijeet",
                "user_email": "XXX@gmail.com",
                "comment_text": "nice"
            },
            {
                "totalc": 2,
                "comment_id": "18",
                "news_id": "104",
                "user_name": "abhijeet",
                "user_email": "XXX@gmail.com",
                "comment_text": "nice"
            }
        ],
        {
            "id": "622",
            "news_type": "any",
            "news_heading": "News head here2",
        },
    }
}];
```

[You can check result here... this is getting repeat inrelavent result comment list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG2xs.png)

Comment: Just change `$row2['wid']` to  `$row['wid']` etc. and data, data2 will end up in the same array? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Why `$row2['greet'] =  $row2;` do this? You may need to rethink your data structure a bit.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkusAO to respond, I have just added new key greet, and under this key, I want to fetch $data2 in while loop, nothing gets result by using $row2['wid'] to $row['wid']

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Samuel I have once again updated the question with actual image result, same problem here, I hope you understand this time. comments results are repeating.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER:

I think I understand what you want to do now. you are trying to create a
sub-array, "greet", in $row containing all of the wallpapers associated with that
news article. To get results you want you don't have to merge the row2 and row
arrays, you just make row2 a part of row1

```
//...
$row2= array();
while($data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    array_push($row2,$data2);
} 

if (count($row2) > 0) {
    $row["greet"] = $row2;
}

//...
```

This code should generate the json you have posted.

merging the arrays would create something like this instead:

```
"id": "30",
"news_type": "image",
"news_heading": "News title",
"news_weburl": "#",
"total_share": "0",
"cat_id": "112",
"category_name": "tech",
"wid": "11",
"wall_title": "tech image wallpaper1",
"wall_image": "image1.jpg",
```

and could only be done with one image

If you were wanting it to look like above if there was only one image you could
change the code like this

```
if (count($images) == 1) {
    $row["wid"] = $row2[0]["wid"];
    $row["wall_title"] = $row2[0]["wall_title"];
    $row["wall_image"] = $row2[0]["wall_image"];
} elseif (count($row2) > 1) {
    $row["greet"] = $row2;
}

//...
```

Comment: Thanks for response @Samuels, I need to merge $data and $data2 in a single array, I have try to clarify in question and code.

Comment: Hi @Samuels, One more example, it's working fine but results are repeating (comments are repeating)

Comment: I suspect that is because you created the `$row2` array outside of the main while loop and are not clearing it with every loop. In the top example I gave I have `$row2= array()` right before the inner while loop. Try adding that.

Comment: results are repeating (comments are repeating)